# sublime 3 git plugin p4diff not working

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I just installed sublime git plugin for sublime 3. I tested most of the git commands in sublime, most of them work. But whenever I use git diff, it throws this error

```
error: cannot run p4diff: No such file or directory
```

I have Perforce P4Merge installed, I can run git diff in terminal and the diffs come up in P4Merge correctly.

Can anybody tell me why it does not work in sublime?

Comment: Have you configured the plugin with the correct location of `p4diff`?

Comment: @MattDMo No, I haven't. Should I config the user settings file for Sublime Git? Can you tell me what value should I put in that file?